# How can I get an RSS feed of my top 50 answers?

Tags: support, feed

How can I get an RSS feed of my top (say 50) answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there isn't an official feed for answers.

You could however use [Stack2RSS](http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/), which takes a [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) request URL and returns the response as an RSS feed. All you need to do is find an API request for what you want.

You can use the [`/users/{ids}/answers`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users) method to return answers from specific users, optionally sorted by votes to get the top answers.

There is also the [`/users/{id}/tags/{tags}/top-answers`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-user-answers-in-tags) method if you are interested in answers from specific tags.

---

This is the feed for your top 50 answers on Stack Overflow:

http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/2.2/users/1900692/answers?pagesize=50&order=desc&sort=votes&site=stackoverflow